# How to prove n_k => k by induction?

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble understanding how to to prove that $n_k \geqslant k$ via induction.

Comment: What is $n_k$??

Comment: $n_k$ is not given. This is in the context of proving that a subsequence will converge to the same limit as the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are asking?  Let's say your sequence starts at $k = 1$.  Then the smallest that $n_1$ can be is $1$.  Thus $n_k \geq k$ is true for $k = 1$.  Now, we assume for induction that $n_k \geq k$ for some $k$.  Since the smallest that $n_{k+1}$ can be is $n_k + 1$, we get
$$
n_{k+1} \geq n_k + 1 \geq k + 1.
$$

Comment: Just beat me to it, have my vote instead :)

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was asking. Thank you very much.